# While loop program in python for storing values divisible by 10

Tags: python-3.x

I cant generate/store values divisible by 10 in factors list

```
factors = []
num = 1

while num <= 100:
  if num % 10:
    factors.append(num)
  num += 1
print (factors)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `num` is divisible by 10, then `num % 10` would be 0.

Answer (score 0):

`num % 10` is `0` for numbers divisible by 10.

`if num % 10` evaluates to `False` for numbers divisible by 10, so your list will contain numbers **not** divisible by 10.

You should use `if num % 10 == 0:`

or if you want to confuse anyone who will read you code (including yourself in a few days):

`if not num % 10:`

Answer (score 0):

The modulus of any number is possible. But if the modulus of a number is equal to 0, it is said to be a factor. so `if num % 10 == 0` is what you need to change/add.

```
factors = []
num = 1

while num <= 100:
    if num % 10 == 0:
        factors.append(num)
    num += 1

print(factors)
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
factors = []
num = 1

while num <= 100:
  if num % 10 == 0:
    factors.append(num)
  num += 1
print (factors)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
factors = []
num = 1

while num <= 100:
  if num % 10 == 0:
    factors.append(num)
  num += 1
print (factors)
```

Or, just simply:

```
factors = []
num = 0

while num < 100:
  num += 10
  factors.append(num)

print (factors)
```

Here, we initially have the value of `num` set to `0`
And we increment it by `10` every time before appending it to the list.
You can also have the value of `num` set to `1` initially and append `10*num` to your list `while num <= 10`
The code for that would be:

```
factors = []
num = 1
while num <= 10:
    factors.append(10*num)
    num += 1       
print (factors)
```